# "Group mean centering" a dummy Variable in R for multilevel analysis: how can i do this?

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, categorical-encoding, predictor, centering

have somebody an idea of how to group mean center a dummy Level 1 predictor in R?

Enders & Tofighi (2007) describe a method to center a dummy variable through substracting the proportion of the comparison group (X=1) from zero for the base group (X =0) and substracting the same proportion from 1 for the comparison group.

Is it possible with a special Rpackage or it´s necessary to calculate it more or less manually?

Reference:

Enders, C. K., & Tofighi, D. (2007). Centering predictor variables in cross-sectional multilevel models: A new look at an old issue. Psychological Methods, 12(2), 121–138. https://doi.org/10.1037/1082-989X.12.2.121

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to some code for centering categorical variables. Note in the comments on this blog that this only works for predictors that have 2 levels.

Hope this helps!

https://hlplab.wordpress.com/2009/04/27/centering-several-variables/